# Aligning two divs while having a table inside another table

Tags: html, css

In the code below, I am trying to align in the following table  "Funny" near the second row, and "Sad" near the third row.

So far, I have thrown a `position: relative;` for the Sad container and "Funny" got right where I wanted, but now I can't get "Sad" to be under it.

Bellow is what I have:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Table fitting</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    .p2 {
      position: absolute;
    }
.t1{
text-align:center;
font-size: 130%;
border:1px solid red;
}
.t2{ 
border:1px solid red;
padding: 5px;
font-family: Roboto;
text-align: center;
}
table{
border-collapse: collapse;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="p1">Funny</div>
        <div class="p2">Sad</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th class="t1">Cats</th>
            <th class="t1">Dogs</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="t1">Catty</td>
            <td class="t1">Rocky</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="t1">Kate</td>
            <td class="t1">Rex</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

I would like some help to align the container that has "Sad" exactly behind the one with "Funny" and near the third row.

Comment: Looks like you are using tables in an incorrect way - seems like you use the outer table for layout purposes (which they should never be used for)

Comment: Tables should only be used for tabular data - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html

Comment: @Reformed is there any particular reason you cannot use a 3rd <td> for "Funny" and "Sad"?

Comment: plese tell your expected output correctly

Comment: Something like this: https://imgur.com/a/MDDyK5I

Comment: Btw, I'm not keen on using "div"-s for the left part, another option (that still has the table on the right) would be just fine).

Comment: @Reformed is my answer work for you?

Comment: Sorry, It seemed that it doesn't work, so I deleted the table and gave up on this idea.

Answer (score 1):

The method that you are doing is completely wrong. This gives your expected output.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Table fitting</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                     <th class="t1"></th>
                        <th class="t1">Cats</th>
                        <th class="t1">Dogs</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                     <td style="text-align:right",class="t1">Funny</td>
                        <td class="t1">Catty</td>
                        <td class="t1">Rocky</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                     <td style="text-align:right",class="t1">Sad</td>
                        <td class="t1">Kate</td>
                        <td class="t1">Rex</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Feel free to ask any further questions!